# YUI Compressor is removing spaces from filter values

Tags: css

I have a css containing filter for adding Grayout images in FF like this:-

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
```

When I use YUI compressor it removes all the spaces between filter values and it becomes like this:-

```
.desaturate{filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svgxmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filterid='grayscale'><feColorMatrixtype='matrix'values='0.33330.33330.3333000.33330.33330.3333000.33330.33330.33330000010'/></filter></svg>#grayscale")}
```

Its removing the spaces which makes it useless in FF.

I also tried moving it to an .svg file but then it gives cross domain issues in FF. Please suggest if anyone has any idea on how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8):

I found out by experimenting with JW.'s idea that you can base64-encode the entire string, except for the final `#grayscale` part and adding the corresponding encoding part, or, even nicer. only url-encode the spaces between xml attributes and/or tag names and separating the matrix values by commas.

So in the end you have:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0,0,0,1,0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

which is compact and doesn't get altered by the css compressor

Comment: On a side note, even though the solution works, applying the gray filter in IE8 and earlier causes loss of multi-channel transparency for PNG files. Haven't found a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

The URL portion of the string (from `<svg` to `</svg>`) needs to be URL-encoded. Or you can put `;base64` after `;utf8` and Base64-encode the URL instead.

But it's incorrect to use spaces in a URL...that's why YUI compressor is messing it up.

Comment: This is the correct answer:  You should be URL encoding the data URL.

Answer (score 0):

I gather if your using the latest version (2.4.7) already, then this is likely something their CSS minifier doesn't account for and you will want to raise a bug report with them at http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/

I could not see any configuration option that would help in this case e.g. minifying blocks on to one line but not removing whitespace in-between.

Answer (score 0):

You can add commas between the feColorMatrix values:

```
<feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,0,0,0,0,0,1,0\'/>
```

but that doesn't fix the issue with the spaces between:
svg xmlns

would love to understand that one too.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue in the PHP port of the compressor (https://github.com/tubalmartin/YUI-CSS-compressor-PHP-port), and tracked it down to a line in the `extract_data_urls` method.

This extracts data urls (as you would expect, given its name) from the body of the css to prevent them being minified. However, it does a little bit of processing before it stores them:

```
$token = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $token);
```

This replaces any run of whitespace characters with nothing, and so strips all the spaces out of the SVG tag. Changing this line to:

```
$token = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $token);
```

fixed the issue for me by leaving a single space present.

As the PHP version is a direct port of the Java compressor, I would assume that this same bug.