# URL- or Base64- encode strings in Compass/SASS

Tags: svg, sass, compass-sass

Is there a way to URL- or Base64-encode a string in Compass or SASS?

I want to create an inline SVG background image, like this:

```
background: transparent url('data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8,'
    + '<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
    + '</svg>') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

(The reason for creating it inline is that some of the SVG's values need to come from SASS variables.)

The problem is, CSS data URLs are supposed to be URL-encoded, or Base64-encoded. If they're not, then tools like YUI compressor [mangle them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949588/yui-compressor-is-removing-spaces-from-filter-values).

I know that you can [encode an image from an external file](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/#inline-image), but I need to encode a string. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I'd prefer to do this all in CSS/SASS, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, so I wrote a custom SASS function:

config.rb:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'base64-encode.rb')
```

base64-encode.rb:

```
require 'sass'
require 'base64'

module Sass::Script::Functions
    def base64Encode(string)
        assert_type string, :String
        Sass::Script::String.new(Base64.strict_encode64(string.value))
    end
    declare :base64Encode, :args => [:string]
end
```

SCSS file:

```
background: transparent url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,'
    + base64Encode('<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
    + '</svg>')) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Comment: if anyone want to include it in `grunt-contrib-sass` gruntfile config like me, put `base64-encode.rb` into your project and add `require: './path/to/base64-encode.rb'` to your `grunt file`. `./` is required to `grunt` to find your plugin relative to project path instead of system gems location.

Comment: could you explain a bit more, cause I tried this, but it fails

Comment: You'll want to use `Base64.strict_encode64` as the normal encode64 function adds a new line every 60 characters, which will break the uri.

Comment: inspired by the title of this question and here: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1460

this is a function to just urlencode and therefor generate less overhead.

 `require 'sass'
 require 'cgi'

 module Sass::Script::Functions
  def urlEncode(string)
   assert_type string, :String
   encoded_svg = CGI::escape(string.value).gsub('+', '%20')
   data_url = "url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encoded_svg + "')"
   Sass::Script::String.new(data_url)
  end
  declare :urlEncode, :args => [:string]
 end`

Comment: Great, this function works for me!. I tried many functions from others, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Also it's available as a function in compass: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/5a015b3824f280af56f1265bf8c3a7c64a252621#L2R4

Comment: With `inline-image`, you provide a path to a file, the function reads the file and encodes its contents. The question is about providing the data to be encoded directly to a function.

Comment: note that `inline-image` does not give the possibility to use variables in an svg, something that people ending up at this issue might have been looking for