# Using JavaScript in a background-image svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a SVG (a cross) which changes the color of the lines based on the hash given to the SVG url using JavaScript.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    <line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />

    <script>
        if (window.location.hash) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('line')[0].setAttribute('stroke', location.hash);
            document.getElementsByTagName('line')[1].setAttribute('stroke', location.hash);
        }
    </script>
</svg>
```

This works perfectly fine as an `<object>` element (`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/svg/cross.svg#ff0000"></object>`), but fails as an `img` or css `background-image`.

How can I make this work as a CSS `background-image`?

Comment: You cannot, SVG used as background image and such is non-dynamic per spec - it's just a static image.

Comment: @WladimirPalant — Interesting… which spec? I would have assumed it would say something [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) but I can't see it.

Comment: @Quentin: Couldn't find it in the spec so it simply seems to be a logical security restriction - see my answer.

Comment: One of the authors of the SVG 1.1 specification created this... http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution myself that works for me.
I'm also using Sass, and with it I have found a base64 encode plugin.
With it, I can write svg in my CSS which is then encoded to base64. And I can also use variables.
The SASS code now looks like this:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,'
                + base64Encode('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" stroke="#{$color-line}" stroke-width="1" /><line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" stroke="#{$color-line}" stroke-width="1" /></svg>'));
```

The base64 plugin is found here:
[URL- or Base64- encode strings in Compass/SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454014/url-or-base64-encode-strings-in-compass-sass)

Comment: You can use data URI with text. You don't need to encode it with base64 (just utf encoding) (base64 encoding [use 33% more bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)):
`background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="1" /><line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="1" /></svg>');`

Comment: I guess, question was in "How to run js when svg used as background", and not the stuff you provided here

Comment: @Velaro did you notice the author of the question is the same person as the author of the accepted answer? Guess he knows best 

Comment: And it was 7 years ago!

Comment: I noticed it, author provided question, answer to which is not related. No matter how old it is, point is that someone may actually face the same problem as me now. (Can I use javascript if I encode-base64? I guess - no! )

Comment: And that is why I prefaced my own answer with "I have found a solution myself that works for me". I just don't understand what you aimed to achieve with your comment.

Answer (score 8):

Dynamic behavior in SVG that is used as an HTML image is [disabled for security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions). The reason is quite obvious - you can use an SVG image from a different domain and wouldn't really want it to run JavaScript code in the context of your document. So SVG used as an HTML image is essentially always static. There are some more details on http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html (thanks @[RobertLongson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) for this link).

There is a work-around in Firefox: if you have *inline* SVG code (can be hidden) you can use a filter from that SVG code using the [`filter` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#url%28resource%29). Depending on what you are trying to achieve this can be a rather [powerful tool](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html). According to MDN Chrome and Safari should also support this but I'm not certain that they do.

Comment: Too bad inline svg isn't an option. Chrome and Safari also support it, but I really needed a background because I can't control the HTML.
But I've found a solution (see my answer)